# Read digits from a number using sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read/extract two digits number using `sscanf`.
facing some issues.

```
char* str = "2019/05/28";
int x,y,z;
sscanf(str, "%d/%d/%d", &x, &y, &z);
It reurns me o/p as 2019, 05, 28 which is ok.
```

But `from 2019` I would like to extract only `19`.

I tried `%2d` it returns `20`. And also I need to check the months are also in two digits i tried all possible ways but no luck yet.

Please help.

Update:
`I also tried %2d%d -> which gives me 19`.
But it is not sure whether I will be `getting 4 digits or 2 digits always`.

Input could be `char* str = "19/05/28";`

Comment: Just after the existing `sscanf()`, use `x %= 100;`.  Will that work for you?

Comment: @chux: That works and currently I am doing in that way only. But are there any way we can evaluate it in `sscanf`?

Comment: Another option is `if (sscanf(str, "%*2d%2d/%2d/%2d", &y, &m, &d) != 3) goto err;`

Comment: Yet another option is to pass `str + 2` like `sscanf(str + 2, "%d/%d/%d", &x, &y, &z);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you want it done in `sscanf`, it can be done this way:

```c
if (sscanf(str, "%*2d%2d/%2d/%2d", &y, &m, &d) != 3)
        goto err;
```

EDIT:

Add some check as an example:

```c
if (sscanf(str, "%*2d%2d/%2d/%2d", &y, &m, &d) != 3)
        goto err;
if (sscanf(str, "%4d", &tmp) != 1)
        goto err;
if (tmp < 1900)
        goto err_year;
```

`sscanf` has a maximum width field, not an exact width field, so you have to check manually if the user inputs a 3 digit year, and think about what to do if so

I wouldn't use it in this case because you still need to read the four digits for the check, so **@chux**'s solution is the best one in this case:

```c
if (sscanf(str, "%4d/%2d/%2d", &year, &m, &d) != 3)
        goto err;
if (year < 1900)
        goto err_year;
y = year % 100;
```

Comment: you are right. but if char* str = "319/05/12"; then reads 9. which should not happen

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak Well, I assumed from the question, that it was a standard date. Specify what kind of data you will receive, and what to do with unexpected data.

Comment: In case of unexpected data, sscanf should fail.

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak And what is unexpected data?

Answer (score 1):

Use x℅=100 to get the last two digits of the year.

Use a check like y<100 to make sure that y is less than or equals to 3 digits. More precisely yoy can write (y<=12). One thing to notice here is, integer ignores leading zeros. So input "05" will be converted to 5.

```
char* str = "2019/05/28"; int x,y,z; 
sscanf(str, "%d/%d/%d", &x, &y, &z);

x%=100;
if(y<=12) {
    //valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read using `"%n"` to record the offset of the scan.

`" %n%d%n", &n1, &i, &n2` leads to `n2-n1` is the character width of the numeric text for `x`.

```
int x1, x2;
int y1, y2;
int n = 0;
sscanf(str, " %n%d%n/ %n%d%n/%d %n", &x1, &x, &x2, &y1, &y, &y2, &z, &n);

// Was the string fully parsed with no trailing text?
if (n > 0 && str[n] == 0) {
  switch (x2-x1) {
    case 2: /* 2 character date */ break;
    case 4: /* 4 character date */ x %= 100; break;
    default: return error;
  }
  if (y2 - y1 != 2) {  // I need to check the months are also in two digits  
    return error;
  }
} else {
  return error; 
}
```